# How to fix Element <PrecompiledHeader> has an invalid value of "/Yu" error in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning by myself and i want to know how to use precompiled headers in my console app. I have read a lot of guides, it seems i am doind everything right but i still get error.

I use visual studio 2019. So i have main.cpp file with code that uses  and  libraries i would like to be precompiled. I have created a file called stdafx.h and have included all libraries there. Then i created stdafx.cpp which only includes stdafx.h. In project properties for stdafx.cpp precompiler headers are /Yc and for main it is /Yu.

stdafx.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
```

stdafx.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

double getInfoFromUser()
{
    double info;
    cin >> info;
    return info;
}

double computeSqrtDiscriminant(double A, double B, double C)
{
    double i{ sqrt(pow(B, 2) - 4 * A * C) };
    return i;
}

double computeX1(double A, double B, double SqrtDiscriminant)
{
    double X1{ (-B + SqrtDiscriminant) / (2 * A) };
    return X1;
}

double computeX2(double A, double B, double SqrtDiscriminant)
{
    double X2{ (-B - SqrtDiscriminant) / (2 * A) };
    return X2;
}

void computePoint1(double X1, double K, double M)
{
    double Y{ X1 * K + M };
    cout << "Первая точка пересечения:[" << X1 << "," << Y << "]" << endl;
}

void computePoint2(double X2, double K, double M)
{
    double Y{ X2 * K + M };
    cout << "Вторая точка пересечения:[" << X2 << "," << Y << "]";
}

double equateX(double B, double K)
{
    double NewB{ B - K };
    return NewB;
}

double equateC(double C, double M)
{
    double NewC{ C - M };
    return NewC;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите уравнение параболы (aх^2+bx+c=0):" << endl;
    cout << "Введите a:";
    double A{ getInfoFromUser() };
    cout << "Введите b:";
    double B{ getInfoFromUser() };
    cout << "Введите c:";
    double C{ getInfoFromUser() };
    cout << "Введите уравнение прямой (Kx+m)" << endl;
    cout << "Введите k:";
    double K{ getInfoFromUser() };
    cout << "Введите m:";
    double M{ getInfoFromUser() };
    B = equateX(B, K);
    C = equateC(C, M);
    double SqrtDiscriminant = computeSqrtDiscriminant(A, B, C);
    double X1{ computeX1(A, B, SqrtDiscriminant) };
    double X2{ computeX2(A, B, SqrtDiscriminant) };
    computePoint1(X1, K, M);
    if (X1 != X2)
    {
        computePoint2(X2, K, M);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp compiles greatly even without precompiled headers, but i want to learn how to use them. If compiled with precompiled headers i get theese two errors:
error : Element  has an invalid value of "/Yu".
error MSB6011: в задачу Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL переданы недопустимые параметры.(i am from Ukraine so i use Russian localization).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{9F202045-E5DB-4685-9FCD-AFA97F3F750B}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApplicationParabolaIpryama</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <ProjectName>ParabolaPryamaya</ProjectName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">/Yu</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">/Yu</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">/Yu</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">/Yu</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">/Yc</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">/Yc</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">/Yc</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">/Yc</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Also if you use the template console or anything else but empty I believe it will automatically create a precompiled header for you.

Comment: You should probably post the relevant parts of the *.vcxproj file too

Comment: where to find the vcxproj file? I also am using the console template and it dont create PCH for me.

Comment: added *.vcxproj to the edit

Comment: Do you really need precompiled headers?  Is the build time saved worth this kind of hassle?

Comment: @CuteDoge01 alright, added to my answer with the MSBUILD Xml value, did you manually type in "/Yu" instead of using the dropdown-box?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Obviously, on a MVCE that's not worth the hassle, but the point of a minimal example is to isolate the problem. That said, the example isn't exactly minimal.

Comment: @MSalters: I'm not referring to the MVCE.  I'm talking in general.  I've stopped using precompiled headers because they don't save me significant build time (even on Windows Apps) and they cause a lot of issues.  Long time ago on slower computers, they were somewhat helpful, but when you changed a header file, the compiler had to recompute the precompiled header anyway.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: True, that's why I use them exclusively for the `<>` system headers. Those don't change short of a compiler upgrade, in which case you needed a recompile anyway.

Comment: @PeterT Wait, there is dropdown box for properties? Oh, god there really is. The problem was that stupid. Thank you so much for help)

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that i was typing manually the /Yu and /Yc in the file`s properties, although there is dropbox-box in the upper right corner. If you use the dropbox the problem fade away.

Answer (score 0):

The translation unit for the precompiled header needs to use `/Yc` instead of `/Yu`.
In your example you need to enable that setting for `stdafx.cpp`

In the GUI this is done like this:
1. Right click the file in the Solution explorer
2. Select "Properties"
3. **Make sure that "Configuration" at the top is set to "All Configurations" and the Plaform setting is what you want it to be**
4. Go to the "C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers" menu on the right
5. Change the "Precompiled Header" setting to "Create (/YC)"

The values in the *.vcxproj file should be

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<!-- ... -->
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
<!-- ... -->
```

and for the precompiled header file

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<!-- ... -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader>Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Alright, configuration was set wrongly, i have done all your steps but i still get error  : Element <PrecompiledHeader> has an invalid value of "/Yu"(now its /Yu). I have done the same steps for main.cpp with /Yu but it hadnt help.